# Debugging C project with GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

First of all, I want to point that I have no C programming background so a more detailed answer will help me a lot. I downloaded a C mp3 decoder project from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/kmlager.com/www/mp3decoder_20020414b.zip) and I need to debug it in order to understand some steps from the mp3 compression algorithm.

I've learned the basics of GDB from different tutorials so I started by compiling the project using the Makefile included, then I ran GDB for the compiled output like this:

```
gdb --args mp3decode test.mp3
```

But when trying to list the files to set a breakpoint I get this:

```
(gdb) list
init.c:1: No such file or directory.
```

Googling a little bit about above output, the more common mistake when compiling is not using the **-g** option however I made sure that option is in the Makefile.

```
CFLAGS = -g -O4 -funroll-loops -Wall -ansi -DOUTPUT_SOUND
OBJS = MP3_Bitstream.o MP3_Decoder.o MP3_Huffman.o MP3_Huffman_Table.o \
    MP3_Main.o MP3_Synth_Table.o main.o remote_control.o audio.o debug.o
```

Then later:

```
mp3decode: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o mp3decode  $(OBJS) -lm
```

What I want to achieve is to set a breakpoint on line 46 of main.c file and then step into the **MPG_Get_Filepos()** method on the same line, but the main.c is not listed in the GDB console.

I think the problem is in the compile command since creates a C object for all files (don't know if I'm wrong) and that's why I cannot debug the code.

What can I do to debug step by step in a project like this? Your help will be appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE:**

This is the command I'm using to compile the program:

```
gcc -g -funroll-loops -Wall -ansi -DOUTPUT_SOUND -o mp3decode  MP3_Bitstream.o MP3_Decoder.o MP3_Huffman.o MP3_Huffman_Table.o MP3_Main.o MP3_Synth_Table.o main.o remote_control.o audio.o debug.o -lm
```

Then I  use GDB with tui to debug it:

```
$ gdb -tui --args mp3decode test2.mp3
(gdb) br main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804ea2e
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jorge/Documents/mp3decoder/mp3decode test2.mp3

Breakpoint 1, 0x0804ea2e in main ()
(gdb) list
init.c:1: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Try these gdb commands: `br main` then `run` then `list`.

Comment: I don't think this solves your problem, but you may want to do initial debugging without the `-O4`.  Optimization produces assembly that can appear to be almost unrelated to the source files in the debugger.

Comment: @n.m the breakpoint is set on main() function but I'm still unable to list files, I get the same output "init.c:1: No such file or directory."

Comment: @AShelly thanks for pointing that, I'll remove that option.

Comment: Did you execute `run`? `init.c` is not a file you are supposed to see. It's a source file from the standard library. If gdb tries to list this file, the program is not stopped in your code.

Comment: @n.m. yes, I ran the program: "Breakpoint 1, 0x0804ea2e in main()" In fact I'm using the tui and I see nothing. When listing I get the same ouput "init.c:1 No such file or directory"

Comment: @n.m. if I set a breakpoint in a method of some of the files, let's say MPG_L3_Requantize() which is in file MP3_decoder.c, I get this: Function "MPG_L3_Requantize" not defined. Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or n)

Comment: The task at the moment is to stop at the first line of `main` and see its code. Do you have a breakpoint on `main`? Are you stopped on it?

Comment: @n.m. ok. Yes the program stops on main function but still can't list.

Comment: Please show *all* of your debugger output.

Comment: @n.m. sorry for the delay, I've updated my question with the debugger output

Comment: I see the link command but not the compilation command. Can you verify that compilation also uses -g flag?

Comment: @n.m. yes, it uses all this flags: gcc -g -funroll-loops -Wall -ansi -DOUTPUT_SOUND

Comment: Your gdb behaves as if the program is compiled without -g. Either it is broken, or you are not running the program you think you're running. Try compiling and debugging a simple "hello world" program.

Comment: @n.m. GDB is working fine with a hello world example, maybe because I don't use object files. Don't know what's happening

Comment: You are not running a debug executable. Clean and remake.

Comment: @n.m. OMG I feel so dumb right now, I ran a make clean and the debugger works fine now!. Now I remember, the first time I compiled the code the -g option was not set but I never erased *.o files, that's why it wasn't working. Would you mind putting the command as answer? That way the question could be closed. Thanks for all your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I didn't delete all binary files specifically C shared objects. After deleting all binary files I recompiled with the **-g** option and then GDB started working as expected.

Comment: I had a similar issue that I switched to another working environment on another computer, and had to **recompile** the files **on the new computer**. Apparently debug symbols were set to relative paths in the previous computer when compiled with `-g`

Answer (score 1):

Check by setting `dir` to source path.

Example: Suppose source code is in `/home/exp/mp3decoder`

then after

`gdb --args mp3decode test.mp3`

```
gdb dir /home/exp/mp3decoder
```

Comment: "Source directories searched: /hone/jorge/Documents/mp3decoder:$cdir:$cwd" but I can't list